# How to use sed in a Makefile

Tags: bash, sed, makefile

I have tried putting the following in my Makefile:

```
@if [ $(DEMO) -eq 0 ]; then \
    cat sys.conf | sed -e "s#^public_demo[\s=].*$#public_demo=0#" >sys.conf.temp; \
else \
    cat sys.conf | sed -e "s#^public_demo[\s=].*$#public_demo=1#" >sys.conf.temp; \
fi
```

but when I run *make*, I get the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 30: unterminated `s' command
```

If I run the exact lines that contain `sed` in the console, they behave correctly.

Why am I getting this error and how can the problem be fixed?

Comment: There's not a lot of point in using cat to pipe input... couldn't you just use stdin redirection in the sed command?

Comment: @Platinum Azure: Yeah, maybe. This is just a version I reached while trying random fixes.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

*TL;DR: Use single quotes **and** use two $ signs. The expression is expanded twice, once by `make` and once by `bash`. The rest of this answer provides further context.*

It might be the $ sign in the substitution that is interpreted by make as a variable. Try using two of them like **.*$$#public_demo**. Then make will expand that to a single $.

EDIT: This was only half the answer. As cristis answered: the other part is that one needs to use single quotes to prevent bash from expanding the $ sign too.

Comment: I guess $$$$ would also work if you can't use single quotes. Eeew.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest you use single quotes instead of double quotes, the `$` might be processed as a special char by make before running sed:

```
cat sys.conf | sed -e 's#^public_demo[\s=].*$#public_demo=0#' >sys.conf.temp;
```

Comment: I used single quotes in the first place and switched to double quotes because I, too, have thought that the single quotes were the problem.

Comment: Actually, I think cristis is correct, regardless of whether my answer is correct or not. $ will be expanded twice, I think: Once in the makefile, per my answer, and once by bash. Using single quotes will prevent bash from expanding the $, but not make.

Comment: Actually you were BOTH right. Using single quotes and $$ fixed the problem. Whose answer do I accept now?

Comment: Good question. I can edit my post and reference cristis answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `make` version in my machine is:

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
```

And the `sed` version:

```
$ sed --version
GNU sed version 4.2.1
```

I must add backslash for `$` to prevent sed taking it as end of line:

```
cat sys.conf | sed -e 's#^public_demo[\s=].*\$$#public_demo=0#' >sys.conf.temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something else than `#` to separate parts.

Comment: I used / in the first place and switched to # because I, too, have thought that the separator was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

one problem I had with using sed in a makefile isn't addressed by the current answers, so I'll explain it here. I was populating Bash variables like so: `remote_owner=$$($(MAKE) remote.owner)` and then using those variables in my sed substitution. problem is, due to the convoluted way my rules are set up, `remote_owner` could have make's own output in it, giving me the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 69: unknown option to `s'
make: *** [alter_table_local.sql] Error 1
```

for example, by adding debugging messages, I found local_owner set to:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jcomeau/rentacoder/jh'
jcomeau
```

the answer was to add the `--silent` option to make: `remote_owner=$$($(MAKE) --silent remote.owner)`

Answer (score 0):

I tried double `$$` sign but it didn't work in my problem, maybe `$$$$` or `$$$$$$$$` would have worked, because my Makefile calls other Makefiles and so on. But I found a better solution:

Create a shell file `replacer.sh` in the same folder as your Makefile that executes the `sed` command. Give it executable bit with

```
chmod +x replacer.sh
```

Now you can call this file in your Makefile:

```
./replacer.sh
```

Comment: Not a good idea. When you call `./replacer.sh` from Makefile that's equivalent to writing the shell code in the Makefile.

Comment: Sure, but why shouldn't that be a good idea? It solves the problem with the double dollars

Comment: I'm compiling openwrt, `$$` and single quotes don't solve my problem, but this method works and also avoids the problem of indentation, I think it's a good solution.